Finding outliers in mostly zero data
Background
I'm working on an algorithm to find a short pieces of DNA sequence in a long DNA sequence. I won't go in detail of how it actually works, but let me more formally state it to provide sufficient context. Each DNA sequence is just a string from the alphabet ATGC. Given the reference, r, we move a window w along the reference r. For example if the reference r were ATGCA and w=3 we would generate the windows ATG, TGC, GCA. Each window is then compared to each query to generate a count, c,  which resembles how well they match. Therby basically producing a matrix with the columns being the window start positions in r and the rows the counts for each window for each query. Based on the experimental data we expect to see a peak of counts on the left and on the right of the reference. However, this is not guaranteed, the left, right or both peaks might be absent and there might be multiple peaks on each side (and even in the middle).
Plots
The colors represent the different queries but legend is omitted as it takes up too much space
Example 1. Most windows actually don't match the queries, and hence zero dominates (see bottom panel, not sure why the plotting library made the bar next to the 0, but the first bar is zero). However, two teal peaks clearly stand out on the left and right having counts beyond 20.

Example 2
Similar to one, however here the left peak is much less pronounced. I would visually say the blue is still higher than "average" it's not as obvious as orange.

Example 3
This is an example where there are multiple peaks on a single side:

The question
My first instinct was using something like z-score, percentile, or IQR to select these high values. However as zero dominates also a count of 3 or 5 is actually considered an "outlier" but not of my interest. I'm really wondering what would be the way to go to "automatically" detect such higher outliers. The main intention is just to minimize the user input as setting a minimum count for example is not intuitive. Also when I set a minimum z-score for instance one peak would pass, but the other not, etc. While visually looking at them most seem obvious I can't figure out a way to neatly detect these.
Curious to see the responses!

Edit 1
One thing I noticed that, since it's a sliding window the correct regions often have multiple good matches that go from bad to peak to bad again as the window slides along the region. This would show up in a cumulative score plot:


The cumulative score curves for the left and right match are much different from the others.  Then maybe I can use any of the curve properties to assess significance. Just checked the end value, AUC, curvature and growth rate:

(in red I just manually colored the green curves above)
Edit 2
In response to Christian.

one time 5 might be good, another time 20 might be good

To put simply, the overall quality of the reference might just be worse. Hence, identifying the "match" with a query is also harder. For example in a high quality example, our query might be "ATGC" and the reference also "ATGC" but in a lower quality example the reference might be "ATGG" (G instead of C). This "noise" is caused sequencing of the DNA molecule. The more noise, the worse the reference, the worse the scores our queries can obtain. When quality is bad a score of 5 might actually be good at least when distinguishable from background signal. However, on a high quality reference 5 might actually be bad and fall within the background signal.

When you talk about z-score and IQR and the like, do you refer to a single start position in isolation or data from all positions taken together?

I used data from all positions taken together (for the same query). With the thought that to distinguish a "true" match from background the background would be the other locations for the same query. Like above, if we would have a count of 5 with position x and a at all other positions-x the count would be 1 it might be a true match. But if all positions-x had a count of 4 I would be less sure.

Also I don't understand exactly what the "scores" and "ranks" are in the "Edit 1" and to what exactly the score curves refer.

My bad, the "scores" are actually the counts I mentioned before. The rank refers to the sorted order.

Would it be helpful to identify outlying positions before identifying outlying counts within these positions?
I'm not sure how this would be different. Wouldn't the positions with high counts also the once that our outlying positions.

Edit 3
First calculating the "average background" by sliding a window across r, averaging the counts, then subtracting this from each window again.

Example of a negative:


why not do a z-scoring, but considering only nonzero values to compute the mean/standard deviation?

@JohnMadden, when I filter out zero the mean is 1, when I filter out 1, the mean is 2 etc. Cause the lower counts really dominate.

Note that there is no generally agreed definition of an outlier, and all depends on the meaning of the data and for what use you want to detect outliers.  "However as zero dominates also a count of 3 or 5 is actually considered an "outlier" but not of my interest." An "automatic" method cannot know this. If you know how high a value is actually of your interest, you could just use that value as a threshold!?

I assume that your objective is to capture the few 'interesting' results for further investigation. In that case you might like to consider a process whereby you tabulate the top few percent (or less?) of the counts and then send the relevant samples for further analysis in decreasing order of interestingness. Adjust the captured fraction to give a workable (or otherwise sensible) number of secondary analyses. In many circumstances a more 'statistical' method will simply hide the arbitrariness of the selections!

@ChristianHennig I don't know what actually makes a good match as that is context dependent one time 5 might be good, another time 20 might be good. Hence it would be helpful to have some value to differentiate it from background noise

Your problem is nonstandard and not easy. You may be better off finding somebody who can devote time to this and is paid and/or can be collaborator rather than asking strangers on the internet to do it for free. I have some ideas but I think more background knowledge is needed to understand what makes sense, and I may not have the time to elaborate them anyway.

Anyway, some questions: "one time 5 might be good, another time 20 might be good" - can you describe the criteria in what situation it'd be rather 5 and when rather 20? That'd make it clearer to us what exactly is the relevant information in the data (and whether this information is in the data at all).

When you talk about z-score and IQR and the like, do you refer to a single start position in isolation or data from all positions taken together? Also I don't understand exactly what the "scores" and "ranks" are in the "Edit 1" and to what exactly the score curves refer. Apparently there is some dependence structure in the problem that probably should be taken into account, and simple methods such as z-score on a single position (or all together) ignore that.

Would it be helpful to identify outlying positions before identifying outlying counts within these positions?

@ChristianHennig see edit 2 hopefully that clears some up. Regarding the advice, I'm a PhD student and totally fine with a collab on the paper. I just thought this was my ignorance in statistics rather than a hard problem to crack. After identifying the outliers I'm not sure the method works at all but at least it seems a better start than saying "count >=5" for example

In your examples the peaks are either at the start or at the end. Isn't this a bit misleading in the sense that in general you wouldn't know where the start/end is? I think it would be relevant/interesting to show what's happening "outside" of your positive examples. Is the "background height" also around 5? Can you compute the background height from properties of the query/windows? Then one way to go about this is looking for small regions with concentrated occurrences above the background.

@dipetkov good point I should've added negative examples (will add). I indeed started with the window approach, however since in the windows low counts always dominate, a count like 4,5 is also three SDs above the mean for example. Actually now you made me think, cant I first create an "average" window (slide a window across r, average the counts), then subtract this from all  then the background should be mostly gone and the distribution is more normal (see edit 3)

Not sure this makes sense but your problem made me think of the procedure for calculating q-values. See the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-value_(statistics). With p-values, most of them are spread uniformly between 0 and 1. (That looks similar to your situation with the background counts?) If I remember correctly, the height of the blue segment in the Wikipedia figure is adjusted automatically. So perhaps you can do something similar & then check whether there's an excess of points above the line at the start/end. (Caveat: This could be a crazy idea.)

I suggest finding the skewness of each count (and maybe each query, it's not clear to me if distinguishing among queries is part of the question or not). Then you can graph the skewness with a line plot (or one plot for each query) and you can set a level of skew that makes you consider the count for a query "different" enough.

How do you propose to measure skewness?  If it's in terms of the third moment, then as an exploratory method this would be ill-advised because it's extremely sensitive to outliers and small changes in the data.

@whuber I just thought of using cumulative scores (see edit 1) would that be something that can be used?

@whuber Being sensitive to outliers is a good thing, since that's what the OP wants to find.

Being sensitive, in itself, is an exceptionally bad thing when looking for outliers.  See the literature on EDA and robust analyses, as well as the literature on outlier detection.
